# Using dxfwrite or ezdxf to create dxf text in z direction

Tags: dxf

I would like to use either `dxfwrite` or `ezdxf` to create text along (`WCS`) y direction, and with height in the (`WCS`) z direction.

Using autocad, I have done this by setting UCS and entering text.

How can I do in dxfwrite or ezdxf (or any other python friendly library)?

```
dxf.ucs('textucs',xaxis=(0.,1.,0),yaxis=(0.,0.,1.))
lab = dxf.mtext('hello',np.array([0.,0.,.5]),layer='mylay',height=0.3)
```

doesn't work, presumably because I have only created `UCS`, and am not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining an UCS does nothing, dxfwrite/ezdxf are not CAD applications.

This example uses ezdxf to write a text in the YZ-plane:

```
import ezdxf

dwg = ezdxf.new('ac1015')
modelspace = dwg.modelspace()
modelspace.add_mtext("This is a text in the YZ-plane",
                     dxfattribs={
                         'width': 12,  # reference rectangle width
                         'text_direction': (0, 1, 0),  # write in y direction
                         'extrusion': (1, 0, 0)  # normal vector of the text plane
                     })

dwg.saveas('mtext_in_yz_plane.dxf')
```

mtext in dxfwrite is just a bunch of TEXT entities, because the MTEXT entity requires DXF13 or later.